# Shaders on XNA/MonoGame particle

Tags: c#, xna, shader, monogame

I'm working on a XNA/MonoGame game and I have this particle engine where, it simulates an explosion.
So, this is the particle engine Draw method:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, sourceRectangle, Color, 0, origin, Size, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

where Color is a random color (because the texture is white)

The thing is, I want to set an effect on each particle, but I can't, because the effect turns the particle back to the original white color!

What am I doing wrong???

This is one of the shaders (but I also tested with others effects)

```
float BlurDistance = 0.002f;
 sampler ColorMapSampler : register(s0);

 float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 Tex: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
 {
  float4 Color;

  // Get the texel from ColorMapSampler using a modified texture coordinate. This
  // gets the texels at the neighbour texels and adds it to Color.
  Color  = tex2D( ColorMapSampler, float2(Tex.x+BlurDistance, Tex.y+BlurDistance));
  Color += tex2D( ColorMapSampler, float2(Tex.x-BlurDistance, Tex.y-BlurDistance));
  Color += tex2D( ColorMapSampler, float2(Tex.x+BlurDistance, Tex.y-BlurDistance));
  Color += tex2D( ColorMapSampler, float2(Tex.x-BlurDistance, Tex.y+BlurDistance));
  // We need to devide the color with the amount of times we added
  // a color to it, in this case 4, to get the avg. color
  Color = Color / 4; 

  // returned the blurred color
  return Color;
 }

 technique Blur
 {
  pass Pass1
  {
   PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Should the division by 4 be declared as a float? e.g. Color = Color / 4f;

Comment: I really don't know... I coult try it but, I think that the problem is not with the shader. If I apply it to other textured object, it works... And, I think it is working with the particle, but I don't see it cause is all white.